# t::lib::TestApp not in CPAN?

Tags: perl, cpan, dancer

I'm trying to install Dancer::Plugin::Feed on Mac OSX 10.6 and I'm running into this dependency problem:

```
CPAN.pm: Going to build H/HO/HOBBESTIG/Dancer-Plugin-Feed-0.7.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for Dancer::Plugin::Feed
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----  HOBBESTIG/Dancer-Plugin-Feed-0.7.tar.gz ----
    t::lib::TestApp [build_requires]
Shall I follow them and prepend them to the queue
of modules we are processing right now? [yes] 
Running make test
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running make install
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running install for module 't::lib::TestApp'
  The module t::lib::TestApp isn't available on CPAN.

  Either the module has not yet been uploaded to CPAN, or it is
  temporary unavailable. Please contact the author to find out
  more about the status. Try 'i t::lib::TestApp'.
```

My Perl verson:

```
perl --version

This is perl, v5.10.0 built for darwin-thread-multi-2level
(with 2 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)
```

I tried to figure out what the problem is without luck.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not that the module isn't on CPAN. [It's there](https://metacpan.org/source/HOBBESTIG/Dancer-Plugin-Feed-0.7/t/lib/TestApp.pm) as part of the Dancer::Plugin::Feed distribution. The problem seems to be that CPAN.pm can't see that it's available within the distribution.

CPAN.pm is seen as a little old-fashioned these days. Have you tried CPANPLUS (which you'll have installed with Perl 5.10.0) or cpanminus?

Answer (score 3):

`t::lib::TestApp` is part of the tests for the module, it's included within the distribution, but is not intended to actually be installed.

However, it looks like the prereqs in `Makefile.PL` were probably auto-generated by Dist::Zilla, and it has seen the `use t::lib::TestApp` statement in one of the tests and added that module to the pre-reqs.

Force-installing the module should work for now; the author of that plugin will need to release an updated version with a fixed pre-reqs list.  I believe I saw this being discussed on IRC earlier, so it seems to be in hand already, but I'll double-check on that.